# Why this code does not schow the expexres values in the textfields

Tags: javascript, window

I have two fields in a form which is openend by the followin function:

```
function fensterauf(URL,orderWindow,properties){


    var newWindow=window.open(URL,orderWindow,properties);

    newWindow.getElementById('newOrder_MaLogin').value="XXXX";
        newWindow.getElementById('newOrder_KdNr').value="YYYYY";

}
```

I controlled the the fields were correctly defined..

Why the concerning values are not sshown in these fields..

Comment: Use the debugger.  That function does not exist on `window`.

Comment: newWindow.document.getElementById